# How can my iOS app know Appium is running it?

Tags: ios, appium

One of the benefits of Appium is that I can run tests against the app without compiling in any instrumentation. But, there's a feature I want to turn off in my app when Appium is the user.

How can Appium can send information directly to the app, to tell it that Appium is driving? This needs to happen shortly after launch, so hiding a secret switch somewhere is not a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `processArguments` capability to pass application launch arguments through Appium to your application. Inside your application you can read the launch arguments and values using `NSUserDefaults`.